# omiting consecutive 8 digits (not numerical) from input

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a task considering validation, I wanted to trim a string if that contains 8 digits in alphabetical form consecutively,  example:

"three four five five two three four one two"  or "threefourfivefivetwothreefouronetwo"

I am wondering if is it some regular expression possible for this or some other suggestion.

It could be either in Javascript or in Java

**Input string :** "*sample string three four five five two three four one two remainimg string*"

or

**Input string :** "sample string threefourfivefivetwothreefouronetwo remainimg string"

my expected string : "*sample string remainimg string*"

Thanks, Jibby

Comment: Could you please update your questions with examples of wanted inputs and outputs? As for now, it's too vague. Besides, should this be done in JS or Java?

Comment: a) Why do you have a Java and a JavaScript tag? b) Do you mean digit words or digits? c) What do you mean by trim? remove those consecutive digits from the word? reject the string altogether? what if there are multiple occurrences of 8 digits? d) What have you tried?

Comment: my try is unaccessible to me now I tried using occurrence of any of them consequetively  I took an array of string contaning these ten digits and iterating through inout and that is lot of code that's why I m searching for shorter variant

Answer (score 1):

This should work for Javascript:

```
str.replace(
    /(?:(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\s*){8,}/g,
    ""
);
```

Comment: This won't match `threefourfivefivetwothreefouronetwo`

Comment: Just modify `{8}` to `{8,}`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, thanks, corrected.  The description only mentioned eight digits, and I didn't notice that the example shows it should match more than eight as well.

Answer (score -1):

If digits are spelled out like in your examples and you need it in JavaScript, then try this:

```
var eightDigitsRegex = /(?:(?:zero|one|two|three|...|nine)\s*){8,}/;
if (string.match(eightDigitsRegex)) {
    // It matches.
}
```

Make sure you add the rest of the digits in the middle of `eightDigitsRegex`.

- `(?:)` is a non-capturing group
- `zero|...|nine` - digit alternatives
- `{8}` - repetition count (the non-capturing group corresponding to any digit will encounter 8 times

**EDIT**: Only regex matching here. Please clarify what *"trimming"* is, exactly. Removing the matched substring? Any whitespace surrounding it?..

Comment: Removing whitespace in a separate step is not desirable, because it mangles the rest of the string and could even create a false positive.  For example: `"on e two three..."` should not match.

Comment: Right, but that was before the question edit which did not mention any surrounding strings. I'm waiting for a clarification to post the complete response.

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the example that trimming means removing the matched portion from the string.

Comment: @dan1111: The details are not that clear, though. What happens if I have `FOOthree fourfive...nine BAR`? Should it become `FOOBAR` or `FOO BAR`?